# Lifespan estimate for system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions, online-resources

My lectures notes on ODE mention the following theorem:

> Proposition (Lifespan): Let $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an interval, $D \subseteq I \times \mathbb{R}$ open, $(t_0,y_0) \in D$ and $f: D \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous and locally Lipschitz with respect to $y$.
> Let $U(t_0,y_0)$ be the neighbourhood of $(t_0,y_0)$ from the local
> Lipschitz condition and $h,c>0$ and define
>
> $$Q:=[t_0,t_0+h] \times [y_0-c,y_0+c] \subseteq U(t_0,y_0),$$
>
> then the maximal interval of existence of the solution to the IVP
>
> $\left\{\begin{array}{} y'(t)=f(t,y(t)), t \in I\\ y(t_{0})=y_{0}\\ \end{array} \right.$
>
> contains $[t_0,t_0+a]$ where $a=min\{h,c/M\}$ with $M=\max \limits_{(t,y) \in Q}  \{\lvert f(t,y) \rvert\}$.
>
> Proof: We define the function
>
> $\tilde{f}(t,y) = \left\{\begin{array}{} f(t,y_0-c), t \in [t_0,t_0+h], y<y_0-c\\
> f(t,y), t \in [t_0,t_0+h], y_0-c<y<y_0+c\\
> f(t,y_0-c), t \in [t_0,t_0+h], y_0+c<y\\ \end{array} \right.$
>
> then for all $(t,y) \in [t_0,t_0+h] \times \mathbb{R}$ the argument of
> $\tilde{f}$ lies in $Q$, and thus in $U(t_0,y_0)$. So $\tilde{f}$
> satisfies a global Lipschitz condition on $[t_0,t_0+h]$, so the IVP
>
> $\left\{\begin{array}{} y'(t)=\tilde{f}(t,y(t)), t \in [t_0,t_0+h]\\
> y(t_{0})=y_{0}\\ \end{array} \right.$
>
> has a unique solution $v$ on $[t_0,t_0+h]$. So for $t \in [t_0,t_0+a]$
> (note that $a \leq h$)
>
> $$\lvert v(t)-y_0 \rvert=\lvert y_0 + \int \limits_{t_0}^{t} v'(s) ds
> > - y_0\vert=\lvert \tilde{f}(s,v(s)) ds \rvert.$$
>
> In addition, $\tilde{f}$ is bounded by $M$ by construction, so we have
>
> $$\lvert v(t) - y_0 \rvert \leq M \lvert t-t_0\rvert \leq Ma \leq M
> > \frac{c}{M}=c$$
>
> It follows that $v(t) \in [y_0-c,y_0+c]$ for all $t \in [t_0,t_0+a]$.
> But this means that for all $t \in [t_0,t_0+a]$, we have
> $\tilde{f}(t,v(t))=f(t,v(t))$, and so
>
> $$v'(t)=\tilde{f}(t,v(t))=f(t,v(t))$$
>
> and $v(t_0)=t_0$. But then $v$ is a solution to the IVP given in the
> theorem on $[t_0,t_0+a]$. So the maximal interval of existence must
> contain at least $[t_0,t_0+a]$.

The author also states that this can be generalized to systems of ODEs, but I could not find anything on google. The idea of the proof for a single ODE is to extend the function to a globally Lipschitz function by changing its values outside of the cube $Q$. My guess is that the same line of argument works for systems, i.e. we need to choose suitable values $h,c_1,...,c_d$ such that the solution does not leave the cube $Q$ in any direction. I think we can restrict ourselves to directions parallel to the axes since these are the shortest paths to get outside of $Q$. However, I cannot see how to define a globally Lipschitz function $g$ that agrees with $f$ on $Q$ in the case of a $d$-dimensional system.

Could anyone please point me to a source that proves this theorem for systems or give a proof for this case?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Define
$$
\psi(y)=y_0+\frac{c}{\max(c,\|y-y_0\|)}(y-y_0).
$$
This is a continuous function with $\psi(y)=y$ for $\|y-y_0\|\le c$ and constant on rays through $y_0$ outside this "ball".

Now define $\tilde f(t,y)=f(t,\psi(y))$ and continue in the same fashion as before.

---

One might have to use
$$
\left\|\frac{a}{\|a\|}-\frac{b}{\|b\|}\right\|
\le\left\|\frac{a}{\|a\|}-\frac{a}{\|b\|}\right\|+\left\|\frac{a}{\|b\|}-\frac{b}{\|b\|}\right\|
=\|a\|\,\frac{|\|b\|-\|a\||}{\|b\|\,\|a\|}+\frac{\|a-b\|}{\|b\|}
\le\frac{2}{\|b\|}\|a-b\|
$$
or better to prove the global Lipschitz property.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I will try to prove it with this function.

Comment: How can we prove $\lVert \tilde{f}(t,y_1) - \tilde{f}(t,y_2) \lVert \leq K \lVert y_1 -y_2 \rVert$ for some  $K$ if one of either $y_1$ or $y_2$ is inside the closed ball $\bar{B}_c(y_0)$. I've managed to prove the other 2 cases, but I am stuck on this one.

Comment: For this case I get $ \lVert \tilde{f}(t,y_1) - \tilde{f}(t,y_2) \rVert \leq L_{t_0,y_0} \lVert y_1 - y_0 - \frac{c}{\lVert y_2 - y_0 \rVert} (y_2 - y_0) \rVert$ and then I don't know hot to continue. I somehow need to manipulate the right side to obtain a $\lVert y_1 - y_2 \rVert from this.$